# How to get selected value from DataGridView combobox dropdown list when checkbox is checked?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` in which I have made a combobox which has drop down list "10","20","30" which are saved in collection. i have a checkbox and i want selected value in `DataGridView` combobox when checkbox checked. suppose i want only "10" in `DataGridView` combobox when checkbox checked. is it possible?

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
      row.Cells(7).Value = 10
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the issue with the code you posted?

Comment: A `DataGridView` is not a `DataGrid`, hence the names being different.  Please use the correct names for things to ensure that there is no confusion.  There are several controls named `DataGrid` and that's why it is also important to specify the technology in use.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The posted code appears to work as expected, and I agree with others that you need to say what is not working as expected. To answer… “Is it possible?” … yes, and you have posted that solution. Is there some other question? FYI, you may want to move the `If CheckBox1.Checked` “outside” the foreach loop… if the check box is not checked, it is unnecessary to loop through all the rows. In addition, if it “IS” checked, it will be “checked” for all rows, therefore it is unnecessary to keep checking its unchanging value.

Comment: row.cell(7). is datagridview combobox not textbox.